# Visual Studio Code | C++ Hello World Creation | Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup a "Hello World" C++ file on my Visual Studio Code, but I am receiving an error message when trying to use a Debugger.

**Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid**.

Here is the helloworld.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Here is the launch.json contence file.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    
    "configurations": [

    ]
}
```

Could someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Please read [the VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/). Especially the section for C++ which matches your setup the closest.

Comment: how about return 0; ?

Comment: @user1095108 Not needed. And is irrelevant to the problem.